# Laravel simple constraint on eager load

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user model, which belongs to one site. One site can have many users.

### User table

- id
- name
- email
- ....
- company_site_id

### Site table

- id
- name

The relationship is defined in User as follows:

```
public function site()
{
    return User::belongsTo('App\CompanySite', 'company_site_id', 'id');
}
```

I want to simply get all users assigned to a site (lets say with a site ID of 1).

```
$users = \App\User::with(array('site' => function($query)
{
$query->where('id', '=', 1);

}))->get();
dd(count($users));
```

However this is returning all of the users irrespective of their site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting all the users that is why, with the use of `->get();`.

Use the `whereHas` method. This will query your relationship and return only the models that have the relation results you are wanting/querying;

```
$users = User::whereHas('site', function($q)
{
    $q->where('id', '=', 1);

})->get();
```

So Users that have site with an `id` of 1 will be returned in this instance.

Comment: Totally makes sense. The docs are a little vague on this, as the example reads as if it would only get the models if the relationship matches the constraint. However, if I use 'with' then it'll return all of the parent model, but only the filtered relationed models. Thanks (again!)